# Nested IF statement on Google Spreadsheet, second part same as the first

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for my budget. Payments are either drawn from my bank or my Amex card and then my Amex card is drawn from my bank as well. So I add up all my monthly total like this:

```
=sumif(I3:I20,"<>AMEX",D3:D20)
```

Where I3:I20 = account bill is paid from and D3:D20 is monthly amount due.
So I am not including bills that come from my Amex card in the total since the Amex bill itself covers those.

Next I have a column that has the day of the month 1-10 (when everything gets paid) and it does this:

```
=sumif(H3:H20,E24:E33,D3:D20)

d|amount due
-------------------
1|$XX.XX
2|$XX.XX
3|$XX.XX
4|$XX.XX
5|$XX.XX
6|$XX.XX
…
```

Where H3:H20 = date bill is paid and E24:E33 = range from 1-10.
What I want to do is make this second part do the same check as the first. Something like
this:

```
=sumif(H3:H20,E24:E33,IF(I3:I20"<>AMEX",D3:D20,0))
```

But I get error: "Parse error"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have "BANK" in I3:I20 (as opposed to "AMEX") for bank payments, then I believe you can achieve your goal by reversing your logic (equal to "BANK", rather than not equal to "AMEX")...

Change the formula in F24 to:

```
=arrayformula(sumif(H3:H20 & I3:I20,E24:E33 & "BANK",D3:D20))
```

This will then populate cells F24:F33 with the appropriate values. `&` is the string concatenation operator, so this effectively compares "1BANK" with "1AMEX" (for instance).

Comment: Works beautifully! I have 2 banks I use (one is for charitable things/tithe) so I just used your solution but added another column for the other bank.